# LibreOffice Calc: sum n largest of a list of cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have got cells, say,

```
B5, C6, H1, I3, J5, L9
```

and I want the sum of the, say, four largest values in that list of values in LibreOffice Calc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer** `=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((B5~C6~H1~I3~J5~L9);ROW(A1:A4)))`

**Description (how to step by step)**

[image: MultipleCells.gif]

Comment: Of course, you can use `{1; 2; 3; 4}` instead of `ROW(A1:A4)` or any other expression that will return an array of numbers from 1 to 4